# Creating a new ElasticSearch index with mapping

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am able to do the following to create a new ES index:

```
>>> es.indices.create(index = 'example_index')
{u'index': u'example_index', u'acknowledged': True, u'shards_acknowledged': True}
```

However, if I add any sort of mapping I get an unknown error. For example:

```
request_body = {
    'mappings': {
        '_doc': {
            'properties': {
                'address': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'},
                'some_PK': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'},
            }}}
}
es.indices.create(index = 'example_index', body=request_body)
```

---

```
> TransportError: <unprintable TransportError object>
```

How would I create a proper index with a pre-defined mapping here? And why does it give such an unhelpful error message?

Comment: try es.indices.create(index = 'example_index', ignore=400,body=request_body)

Comment: @Gimhani same thing.

Comment: here (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/332) , the same error is occuring due to mismatched version. may be this is helpful to you.

Comment: @Gimhani it had to do with not having Java installed locally (even though ES is on a separate server). Installing it fixed this.

Comment: great. you can add this as the answer for this question urself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was only trying to connect to an external ES server, and did not think I needed it installed locally, installing this locally and making sure that Java was installed fixed the above issue.

It seems that the `Elasticsearch` module may need both `java` and `ElasticSearch` installed locally for some of the calls it does, even if not using a local ElasticSearch cluster.